# mysql query 3 tables php output name instead id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Need some help.
I have got 3 tables. klients, klientwithservice, service.

```html
table klients
id | klientrnd
---------
1  | 11231231  
2  | 22222222  

table service
id | servicename
---------
1  | Repair laptop
2  | Repair pc

table klientwithservice
id | klientrnd  | serviceid
-------------------------------
1  | 11231231  | 1
2  | 11231231  | 2
3  | 22222222  | 1
4  | 22222222  | 2
```

I need to output `SERVICENAME` instead `ID`. 
My sql query is:

```html
SELECT serviceid FROM klientwithservice WHERE '$pole8' = `klientrnd`
```

Where `$pole8 = klientrnd` exactly person on which page i placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this you need to JOIN two table

use below query

```
SELECT s.servicename FROM klientwithservice as kws
JOIN service as s ON s.id = kws.serviceid
WHERE  `klientrnd` = '$pole8'
```

Comment: May u can help me anymore?)

Comment: if in second table (service), i have got 3rd column - price how to add this table in outpu query (example: repair pc - 50$) Tnx

Comment: SELECT s.servicename,s.price FROM klientwithservice as kws
    JOIN service as s ON s.id = kws.serviceid
    WHERE  `klientrnd` = '$pole8'

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your sql `SELECT serviceid FROM klientwithservice WHERE '$pole8' = klientrnd` is wrong.

It will return a syntax error stating the `unknown column $pole8` (it's exact value) `is wrong

Second you should use `join` to achieve what you're after. Try this:

```
SELECT s.servicename FROM klientwithservice  as k
JOIN service as s ON s.id = k.serviceid
WHERE  k.klientrnd = '$pole8'
```